# Calling SQL Server Stored Procedure in Spark

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a stored procedure which I am trying to run via `Spark`. The reason to store it as a stored procedure because the database contains a table which needs to be updated. The table stores the last execution time of the stored procedure.

I have tried the two following things:

Method 1:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from createconnection import sql_connection
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys
def getdata():
    url, uname, pwd = sql_connection()
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").getOrCreate()
    try:
        jdbcDF = spark.read \
                .format("jdbc") \
                .option("url", url) \
                .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
                .option("prepareQuery",'EXEC dbo.GetUserDetails') \
                .option("query", 'SELECT * FROM @ResultTable') \
                .option("user", uname) \
                .option("password", pwd) \
                .load()
        jdbcDF.show()    
        # Flush the output to ensure it is sent immediately
        sys.stdout.flush() 
        spark.stop()
    except ValueError as error:
        print("Connector write failed", error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getdata()
```

In `Method 2`  I tried `.option('query','EXEC dbo.GetUserDetails')`, `Method 3`: I tried putting the full SQL Stored Procedure inside `.option('prepareQuery',sql_stored_procedure_code) \ .option('query','SELECT * FROM @SP_RESULT')`. But nothing seems to work. Is there any way to call `stored procedures` inside spark?
I want to know if stored procedure can at all be executed via spark or does it needs to be broken down to multiple sql statements inside the spark script and how to do that.
Any help or guidance is appreciated to proceed with this problem.

Comment: shouldn't it work if your stored procedure populates a more global table with data and then you fetch from that table? SELECT * FROM @ResultTable of course cannot work cause the variable table isn't available as soon as you leave the procedure scope

Comment: I don't think it supports non-tabular access. Any time I've seen anyone use stored procedures in the vicinity of PySpark it's always been using `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` and going through JDBC or `java.sql`.

Comment: yeah, but they recently added this prepareQuery to handle CTEs and other weird sql server stuff, so i suspect it should work

Comment: @siggemannen I was wondering if you have any links as references to your suggestion and how it needs to be done? I will appreciate if you could provide me with one if you have any. Also I want to clarify are you suggesting to populate a physical table or temporary table instead of a table variable in the database and then fetch it from there?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I will also request if you know any reference link to what you are suggesting and please provide me one so that I can look it up.

Comment: Read about prepareQuery here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in calling the `stored procedure` from `spark` is because I was trying to keep a track of start-time and end-time in a SQL Table. Therefore, everytime the `spark` scripts executes it will update the table. However, due to complications I just moved that table to a `.json` file in the spark directory and handle the file as a `json object` to make necessary changes. Therefore, finally I just used the below code in spark.

```
.option('query', f'''
                SELECT 
                  sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(__$start_lsn) as Transactiontime, 
                  ID as TBID, F_NAME as CustomerName
                FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_UserDetails(
                    sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_UserDetails'),
                   sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all'
                )
                WHERE sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(__$start_lsn) BETWEEN 
               '{start_time_str}' 
                AND '{end_time_str}'
            ''')
```